# How to find the client network speed

Tags: c#, networking

I am sending a file from client to server. Both the client and server applications are running in the same machine. After a sending a file from client to server, now I need to show the time it will take to transfer the file from client to server in .Net. Same as copy box in windows xp.

Any idea would be appreciate.

Comment: What are you using to "send" the file from the client to the server? Or how are you doing it and what protocol are you using? I assume the client is a GUI app? What about the server? Please also either fix the typo of clarify "after sending the file to the server, now I need to show the time it will take". Well, are you saying the time it took? Or are you saying before sending the file or are you saying while sending the file? Note that you can only "estimate" while the file is being sent, not before.

Answer (score 0):

You can remember the size of the file, and divide it by the time it took to transfer the file. This will give you a transfer speed estimate (for instance, kilobytes / second).